# How to create a private certificate for connecting to a website

Tags: apache, ssl, private-key, digital-certificate, self-signed

My apologies if this is a duplicate, I may just not be using the correct terminology in my queries to find what I am looking for.

I have a vendor that sent me a certificate to install in my browser so that we can access their website. We cannot get to their pages otherwise.

We similarly have a server for our distributors that has a self signed certificate currently, but we would like to implement the same private certificate system.

What is this process even called? Where do I get started?
Is it just more options when creating the self signed certificate?

Comment: This question is sort of broad.  Maybe start with http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol and then come back with more specific questions.  It's not clear if you are asking "how do I configure my web server" or "how do I generate a certificate" or something else...

Comment: That is exactly what is described in the link I posted in my first comment.

Comment: I've added the answer.  Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use client-side SSL certificates for authentication.  [The Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol) covers this use case in some detail (that's for version 2.4; see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol) for version 2.2).